How to override uppy js file uploader to normal file uploader in 2.4.7
first i have upgrade magento version 2.4.6 to 2.4.7 beta.Admin product form image uploader not working.please anyone some suggestion ?


If the image uploader does not work after upgrade check for error related to jquery/uppy (console). If that's the case you probably forgot to update/add the new libraries in lib/web
